# Every group of order 1000 is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Here is how far I am:
$1000 = 5^{3}\cdot 2^{3}.$ Number of $5$-Sylows is $1$ mod $5$ and has to divide $8,$ so its $1$ making it normal. Lets call it $F.$ Then $G/F$ has order $2^{3}$ and is thus solvable and $F$ has order $5^{3}$ so is solvable implying $G$ is solvable.

Is this correct?
Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me...

Comment: Yes, it is...assuming, of course, you know a finite $\;p$- group is solvable (Well, even nilpotent) .